# How do you work Discord Musicbot on multiple servers?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a music bot using discord.py
But I have a problem.
That is, the bot only works on one server.

this is the main code:
Bot.py

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.load_extension("MusicCommand")
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(bot))


@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx):
    bot.unload_extension("MusicCommand")
    bot.load_extension("MusicCommand")
    await ctx.send("reload!")


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)

bot.run('token')
```

MusicCommand.py

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

class MUSIC(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command(name="join", aliases=['j'])
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if not self.bot.voice_clients:
            if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
                await channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("error"); return 0
    
    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=['exit'])
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await self.bot.voice_clients[0].disconnect()
        
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MUSIC(bot))
```

Suppose there are servers A and B

If you use the join command on server A, you enter the voice channel.
But while the bot is on server A's voice channel,
doesn't work even if you send the join command from server B.

Conversely, if you use the leave command on server B, the bot on server A leaves the voice channel.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your if-statements, instead of checking if the bot is connected to any voice channel in any guild, you should check it per-guild:

```py
class MUSIC(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command(name="join", aliases=['j'])
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
                await channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("error"); return 0
    
    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=['exit'])
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.leave()
```